# Absolute child collapses parent to zero height only on Safari

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser, css-position

I've read many questions about absolute positioning and its quirks, but none of them really gave me an answer, so here goes...

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Zvb9/), with the following HTML and CSS :

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inline-div">
        <label>
            Test
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="next-in-line"><input type="text" /></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.wrap {
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px dashed grey;
}

div.inline-div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

div.next-in-line {
    display: inline;
    clear: both;
}

label {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 32px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

input {
    padding: 15px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

I've highlighted the problematic `div` with a red border. On Chrome, FF, and IE, even though the child element is positioned absolutely, you can clearly see a red rectangle. Apparently the `div` takes its height from its child element. It also has a width (induced by the padding-right property)

On Safari, the div's size is always 0x0, which actually seems more logical : the child element is positioned absolutely, so the parent should collapse. Why is Safari the only browser to behave this way ?

**Given this HTML**, how can I achieve the same layout in all browsers, with the label positioned inside the input box ?

I repeat : I cannot make any modifications to the HTML, only the CSS. Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The red box looks the same in Safari (7.0.1) as it does in latest Chrome. The box with red border has a height and width.

Comment: @myajouri : Ah, I have the bug on Safari for Windows! But since it's discontinued, I guess I'll ignore it then :) Thanks for trying it out on a more recent Safari. If you want to post that as an answer (that my bug only seems to affect Safari for Windows), I will gladly accept it. Else, I may just delete the question because it's not contributing much to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yeah I would ignore Safari for Windows too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to only happen in Safari for Windows. I have tried your fiddle in Safari 7.0.1 on OSX and the red box looks as it does in latest Chrome (the red box does have a width and height).